# Replace values in pandas data frame conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets loaded into Pandas DataFrames from Excel files. I'm trying to replace the Cases value in **d1** from **d2** where the County name matches.

Here are two example datasets:

```
d1 = { 
  'County': ['Armstrong', 'Bailey', 'Bexar', 'Borden', 'Briscoe', 'Carson', 'Castro'],
  'Cases': [80, 548, '', 'online', 58, 'online', 0]
}
d2 = {
  'County': ['Bexar', 'Borden', 'Carson', 'Castro'],
  'Cases': [16891, 1296, 1674, 1985]
}
```

I'm new to Pandas and could really just use some guidance if not a complete answer.

I'd expect `print(d1.to_string())` output to look like this after the merge/replacement has been completed:

```
Name       Count
Armstrong  80
Bailey     548
Bexar      16891
Borden     1296
Briscoe    58
Carson     1674
Castro     1985
```

Comment: Say, `df1.values()`, cannot work since `df1` is a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). My approach deals with [`dict`s](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) not `dataframe`s.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Sorry for the confusion and thank you so much for your thorough answer. I hope my edit clarifies things for you and/or others.

Comment: The point is that you have modified your question in such a manner that my original answer is not relevant anymore.

Comment: I understand and have recently modified for **hopefully** improved clarity.  I couldn't figure out how to submit a comment on your response that is formatted appropriately. Thanks again for your efforts!

Comment: With your `df1` and `df2` in hand (those generated from `d2_path` and `d1_path`), something you can do is `data={**df1.set_index('County').T.to_dict('index')['Cases'], **df2.set_index('County').T.to_dict('index')['Cases']}` and then use this just created `data` object as shown in my answer: `pd.DataFrame(index=['County'], data=data).T.rename_axis('Name', axis=1)`. I won't change my answer though, since it is consistent with your (rolledback) question.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I marked your answer as the solution. I'd prefer to learn how to do this purely in Pandas, but if there's no simple way, I'll move on with your solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: See my edit @octo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).set_index('County')
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).set_index('County')
>>> df1.update(df2)  # works "inplace"
>>> df1
           Cases
County          
Armstrong     80
Bailey       548
Bexar      16891
Borden      1296
Briscoe       58
Carson      1674
Castro      1985
```

?

Comment: Any question @BobZavala ?

Comment: Hi @keepAlive thank you so much for the prompt response!
This works with the example data I've supplied, but doesn't work when I move it to the python file. There are some differences in the actual data, so I'll post the function I'm working with here. Sorry if this caused double-work, I was trying to present what I thought was a simplified question.

Comment: Any question @octopusbones ?